# Variational characterisation of Neumann eigenvalue

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sobolev-spaces, variational-analysis, p-laplacian

Let $1<p<\infty$ and $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded smooth domain. Consider the Neumann eigenvalue problem:
$$
-\Delta_p u=-\text{div}(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)=\lambda|u|^{p-2}u\text{ in }\Omega,\,\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}=0\text{ on }\partial\Omega,
$$
where $\nu$ denotes the outward unit normal vector to $\partial\Omega$. Then the first nontrivial Neumann eigenvalue of the above problem can be characterised as:
$$
\lambda_1=\inf_{\{u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)\setminus\{0\}\}}\left\{\frac{\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}^{p}}{\|u\|^p_{L^q(\Omega)}}:\int_{\Omega}|u|^{p-2}u\,dx=0\right\}.
$$
I saw in many references this characterisation is written in a straightforward way, but I could not find a proof of this fact. Can someone please help me with the same. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the source of this PDE?

Comment: Please have a look art equation (3) and (6) for example in https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6544/ab47c5/pdf

Comment: I also attached the following reference, see page 4360 in https://www.jstor.org/stable/23562194#metadata_info_tab_contents